# HDD Performance Log on VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do I check how many times the HDD was accessed during a program debugging? If I can do this with built in tools, can I also monitor specific files to see how many times they were accessed by a debugging program? I have a program that's taking a huge performance hit and, I have a sneaking suspicion it's reading an XML file too many times.

Comment: I believe this link might help you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Due to buffering there may be a large difference between the application's reads/writes and actual disk I/O.  Is the XML something you can buffer in memory explicitly?

Comment: Kind of, I'm loading the XML through XDocument and passing the XDocument to all those who need it. But, whats even weirder is that when I go into the performance analysis, it doesn't cause the performance hit any more.